# Python basemap module NotADirectoryError: [Errno 20] Not a directory: _/_/epsg

Tags: python

I have troubles to import the basemap module of mpl_toolkits in python. Please Help. Thanks

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NotADirectoryError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_116054/3341290477.py in <module>
----> 1 from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mpl_toolkits/basemap/__init__.py in <module>
    156 
    157 # create dictionary that maps epsg codes to Basemap kwargs.
--> 158 epsgf = open(os.path.join(basemap_datadir, 'epsg'))
    159 epsg_dict={}
    160 for line in epsgf:

NotADirectoryError: [Errno 20] Not a directory: '/home/users/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/basemap_data_hires-1.3.0-py3.9.egg/mpl_toolkits/basemap_data/epsg'
```

My package installed:

```
basemap                            1.3.1
basemap-data                       1.3.0
basemap-data-hires                 1.3.0
```

Comment: I have found the solution, how I just copy the epsg file in basemap_data to the error folder

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.